# Fcitx-unikey indicator icon too large Xubuntu

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce, fcitx

How can I make it become normal (would be a "v" letter)?

[image: fcitx-unikey icon too large indicator]

Answer (score 1):

I've [found two paths](https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx-unikey/blob/master/data/CMakeLists.txt) that related to fcitx-unikey icon:

```
install( ... DESTINATION ${FCITX4_PREFIX}/share/fcitx/imicon/)
install( ... DESTINATION share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/)
```

I checked out that two directories below do exist in Xubuntu 16.04 LTS:

1. `/usr/share/fcitx/imicon/`
2. `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/`

There is a file `unikey.png` 256x256 pixels in the first directory, and a file `fcitx-unikey.png` 256x256 pixels in the second directory.

Then I've scaled those two icons to 96x96 pixels (maybe you want to backup those first), logout, login, and the fcitx-unikey's icon display fitted perfectly for me.